# AWS IoT DynamoDB Create Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I am trying to setup a AWS IoT rule to send the IoT incoming data into the DynamoDB, I think everything has been setup correctly such as the policies.

What I do not understand is what information is needed in the rule, to send the incoming data to the database?

[image]

Comment: please explain what problem you are facing and what are the steps that you have followed ?

Comment: I have created the certificates and policies and checked everything is working via MQTT by sending a JSON packet and I can see the data within the test screen.  I then created the rule, added the DynamoDB table and rules to store the data into the database, I have two elements Device_ID and timestamp with the Hash value ${Device_ID} and ${timestamp()}. Added the permissions to the user policy to access the database. The only thing which could be wrong is defining the rule?

Comment: then what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: When I send the JSON packet the data is not been stored into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the mqtt topic name in your iot query

```
select * from topic_name;
```

Also here is the short guide about how you can get data from AWS iot to dynamo db for quick reference

[Iot Rule to insert data into dynamo db](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html)

Comment: please follow this document if something you don't understand let me know

Comment: Many thanks, I have used that as my guide. What I do not understand and I am sure it's something really simple it SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/your-button-DSN' . Were does the the 'iotbutton/your-button-DSN' information from from?

Comment: the example is for iot button instead of iot button you should use mqtt topic here

Comment: i'm asuming you are not using iot button are you ?

Comment: Many thanks, you just notice I was not using the '' in the topic and why it was not working. Many thanks for the quick response and support